# I am going in circles to get a wordpress user authentication functions in my plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a requirement that I need to double check the user credentials in a wordpress page.

1. I created a plugin and in it are my page templates.
2. I create a user input form that is only displayed for logged in user, but before submission I am gathering username and password and I wish to check it with the currently logged in wordpress user with some functions like :

   ```
   wp_authenticate_username_password
   $userdata = get_user_by('login', $username);
   global $current_user
   ```

etc.

The form is simply like :

```
<!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textInput1">User Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="textInputUserName" class="form-control input-md" name="textInputUserName" required="" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Same credentials ..." />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="passwordinput">Password </label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" type="password" placeholder="******" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

I can call the wordpress functions at the form level, but I am unable to call it in a php script where I process my form in my custom plugin called processRequest.php. I have tried to include the files like

```
require_once ( '../../../wp-includes/user.php');
require_once ( '../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```

but I cannot get those functions working. This is my first wordpress work and I don't know much about the related web technologies like Javascript and php, I only dabble in codes.

Can someone knowledgeable help me please ? How can I get this working ?

Thanks
Alam

P.S :
I want to double check and also take in the same credentials of my website to create an account  at another server offering a different service.  The problem isn't what Wordpress functions I should use , but how to use them ? Because all of them works in the form template file , but fail in my php script file which is deeper in my plugin. What settings am I missing ?

Comment: Why re-authenticate a user when they're already logged in? Have you tried `wp_check_password()`?

Comment: I want to double check and also take in the same credentials of my website to create an account  at another server offering different service.  The problem isn't what Wordpress functions I should use , but how to use them ? Because all of them works in the form template file , but fail in my php script file which is deeper in my plugin. What settings am I missing ?

Comment: You mention that you use your own plugin. How do you register this plugin? Is it visible in plugins page on admin and is it possible to switch on/off? Because functions from `user.php, etc` must be available in your plugin if everithing is right throw registering.

Comment: Hi pgk, the plugin is visible in plugins page, I can switch it on/off. I didn't understand "if everything is right throw registering."